# Post-installation script in Jpackage for Windows

Tags: java, windows, wix, windows-installer, jpackage

I have been exploring jpackage to create installers for an app and I have already created installers for both MacOs and Linux.
Now that I'm trying to create an installer for Windows I came across a problem, while MacOs and Linux both offer the possibility of having a post installation script Windows seems to have nothing of the sort.
My application needs to register some entries in the windows registry and I'm at a loss of how i could achieve this using jpackage.

I've been using [Override Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-62412365-821D-4736-A20D-70F2D47136D8) as my reference.
I have tried using the Post-image script but it seems like I misunderstood what it does and it doesn't actually run during the installation.
I am now looking at the .wix files to see if that would allow me to achieve what I need but I have never worked with the Wix Toolset.

Is anyone aware of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a way to solve the problem:
Jpackage allows us to edit the `main.wxs` file. In this file, if we want to add either a command or in my case a RegistryKey, we can. Just add

```
<Product>
    ...
    <Component Id='SomeComponent' Guid='SomeGUID' Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCR/example/location" Key="foo" >
           <RegistryValue Name="bar" Value='YourValue' Type="string" />
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</Product>
```

And inside feature:

```
<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="!(loc.MainFeatureTitle)" Level="1">
    ...
    <ComponentRef Id="RegistryComponent"/>
</Feature>
```

This should add your custom registry key in `HKCR/example/location/foo` and a string key `"bar"` with value `"YourValue"`.